# 10w led getting too much hot

Tags: led, dc, 12v, adapter

I am using 10w led & lighting those with 12v dc, but they are getting much too hot. What should I do?

I have put those in parallel and am using 12v 2 amp smps adaptor. I am thinking about using resistors but I'm not sure is that gonna work or not. I don't even know how to use the resistors...

Another question; may I charge a lead acid 12v 45/cell battery with a 12V 2A adaptor?

Comment: Forum rules: One question at a time.
Do your best to use good english.. this includes proper paragraphs. Accommodation is made for English as a second language, but that's no excuse for stream-of-consciousness. Show your work and provide as much information as possible.

Welcome to EE:SE!

Comment: Is it properly heatsinks? These large, powerful LED chips put out several watts of heat even when operating correctly, and that heat must be adequately dissipated to keep the die at a safe temperature.

Comment: We can be specific ONLY if you are as specific as possible re what the parts are that you are using . We love to help (or most of us do :-) ) BUT we must know about what you are using .  || Are they modules with a number of LEDs in series and rated at 12 V or are they rated at a lower voltage?. Photos are useful - sharp, well lit, not too small. Do you have a spec sheet or source web page - web address please. LED strips are made (usually) to operate without heatsinks but LED modules almost always need heatsinks.

Comment: where's your datasheete and heatsink design buddy

Comment: what does  45/cell indicate?

Comment: @Daniel there is nothing that I can find in the help center that says you can't ask multiple questions, if you ask too many I could see that as being broad but this question is not.

Comment: @laptop2d maybe it should be spelled out that "Ask question" means "Ask **A** question", not ramble on about loosely related electronics topics....

Answer (score 4):

Oh boy. As I read your question, I get the impression that you are directly connecting your LEDs to a 12 volt, 2 amp power supply - I'm surprised your LEDs are still alive.

First, if you are going to mess around with this stuff, you need to get a cheap DMM. Don't think you can work around this. Don't whine or complain that you can't. Just do it.

Second, power is voltage times current. If your supply is really putting out 12 volts at 2 amps, you are dissipating 24 watts, which is well above your nominal 10 watts, so of course the LED is getting hot. However, it is possible that the power supply is in current limit (which is the mark of a good supply - when it is asked for more current than it can supply, it lowers the output voltage). For instance, [this LED](http://lighthouseleds.com/downloads/dl/file/id/145/10w_led_cool_white_datasheet.pdf) has an absolute maximum current of 2 amps. If this is characteristic of your LED, and the power supply is properly behaving, you may be all right. Just barely. I suspect that your power supply output is running at about 10.5 volts under load, but since you don't have a meter, there is no way to check.

Third, have you heat-sunk your LED? I suspect not, but I thought I'd ask. You must provide a way to cool your LED, and this is usually done by mounting it to a metal heatsink with lots of fins. As the LED heats the heatsink, air flowing over the fins cools it. If you don't do this, you can kill your LED even when operating within normal voltage and current. Also, it's a good idea to get either silicone grease or a Sil-pad to put between the LED and the heat sink in order to make heat flow easier. If you use grease or heatsink compound, use a very, very thin layer.

Fourth, I'm afraid that, although you don't know anything about resistors and voltage and current, you're going to have to learn. I simply don't have the space to teach you, but you can start with this - yes, you must use a resistor between the power supply and the LED. For a 12-volt power supply and a 10 watt white LED, you want about a 2 ohm resistor rated at 2 watts or better. You can buy these from places like digkey, Allied Electronic, Newark, and Mouser.

Do not connect 2 LEDs in parallel - use a separate resistor for each LED. Although the LEDs you have are clearly pretty robust, if you get into the habit of paralleling LEDs sooner or later you're going to kill some. So don't get in the habit.

Finally, in case you ever want to ask another question here, do the following, Don't just describe what you're doing. Draw a wiring diagram or schematic - there is a schematic entry tool as part of the "ask a question" form. It looks like a diode and pencil, or you can simply hit ctrl-m. If you're asking about a particular part, such as you LED, provide a link to a data sheet. If possible, take a picture (a good picture, not some fuzzy blobs) and attach it. Remember that we are not psychic. No matter how much you just know what you're talking about, we don't. We can't read minds, so you have to give us all the information you can.

Comment: I don't think it's _that_ surprising the LEDs are still alive - the PSU's output would be clamped down to the forward voltage of the LEDs and if it's a semi-decent power supply it'll probably enter current limiting mode at that point. The 2A (or a bit more for margin between rating and limiting point) will be divided pretty cleanly across both LEDs in parallel so the power dissipated in each will be in the ballpark of 1A * Vf. If Vf is 4V the power dissipated in each LED is 4W. Enough to run them extremely hot if not heatsinked properly, but not quite enough for instant catastrophic failure.

Comment: @Mels - Eh. Maybe so, but there's no way to tell. OF COURSE he didn't provide a data sheet. Look at the linked LED - at 12 volts it draws 1.2 amps for 14.4 watts. And with no heatsink (pretty much guaranteed here), there's trouble coming.

Answer (score -2):

All parts that dissipate heat have both an incremental effective series resistance (ESR) and a thermal resistance Rjc depending on chip thermal conductor size and conduction to ambient. The thermal performance is very dependent on heat sink design.

Normally when 10W heat source is adhered to an aluminum substrate circuit board (Alum.-clad PCB) it needs roughly 1 sq.in. of surface area per watt to be cool using both sides with convection air. Thus 10 W would need a large surface or a special finned design with air fluid heat transfer velocity from riding heat.

This is why LED designs have much greater surface area in a condensed size with many fins.  The heat density or Watt's/sq.mm requires good thermal design and the package is rated in ['C/W]. This is usually given for both **j**unction to **a**mbient Rja( no sink) and junction to **c**ase Rjc.

When you add interface thermal resistance and heatsink Thermal resistance sink to **a**ambient it is lower than just junction to ambient,

Rjc+ Rcs+Rsa = Rtotal then multiply by Pd [W] to get T ('C)  rise above ambient ( differential temperature).

A good design is <60'C junction rise, a super design is <20'C rise but affects cost, so tradeoffs are made.

It can be hot but desired is not too hot to touch to limit aging rate.

Also White power LEDs have an internal voltage threshold  and then an internal bulk resistance, Rs or ESR(effective series resistance ) like an ideal Zener +Rs.  Rs or ESR reduces as Pd power rating of LED increases such that ESR*Pd is almost constant =1 (+/-50%). (1)

You can use this to estimate the current and voltage rise when applying an array of say 4 series LEDs or roughly 12V and then determine how hot it gets when battery rises to 12.5 or being charged with 14V. Power rises very fast above 12V.

So good designs in cars will use a DC-DC regulator to maintain constant current for voltage fluctuations and good heat-sinks to maintain temperature rise.

If you search this site for other answers on power LED's you can learn more.

Regarding Lead acid batteries, yes you can charge with any current as long as V+ does not exceed 14.2V  When loaded, <10% charged is approx. ~11.5V and 12.5V is approx. 100% charge. Voltage above this is due to internal absorption that fades quickly when loaded and charger is removed.

(1) Diode ESR [Ω] ~ 1/ Pd[W]...This is my Rule of thumb (+/-50%)
The threshold approximation for white LEDs is Vth=2.8V {@ 10% of rated current)

thus  Vf= Vth + If/Pd. {with a wide tolerance due to quality of diode, but Vth is the same for all no matter on Pd rating)

Comment: p.s. they didn't teach me this 5 yrs of EE at Univ back in the early 70's.  It came in my 1st year of experience and later analyzing LEDs when they came out to find they behave exactly like Zeners and power transistors for analysis purposes, while doing other things in my career.

Comment: shame on those who cast a vote of -1 and make no effort to justify it.